# What is PSU that I need?

Tags: desktop

I have these parts, but I am lost because I'm not sure what kind of PSU I need. For the voltage, I can be safe and get a high one, but for the cables included, I don't know what I need.

1. ASRock motherboard Motherboards Z370 PRO4
2. DEEPCOOL GAMMAXX 400 CPU Cooler
3. Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1060 Windforce OC 3GB GDDR5
4. Seagate 1TB BarraCuda SATA

What is the best PSU that I should get my hands on?

**EDIT**

I have calculated that I need 330w, but to be safe I'll go for 500-550 not higher because i am on a budget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a PC, choosing a PSU is quite simple.

Most people do not give importance to find the right PSU. But, I personally consider PSU to be a very vital part of a computer. I myself build my first PC recently and I will share with you how I chose the right PSU.

1. Wattage:
   The parts that you included has their own power(wattage) requirement. There are other parts of a computer that might require the power from the PSU. So, you got to make of list of all the items in your build - Processor, CPU cooler, Memory, GPU, Case fans, HDD/SDD and any other part that does not have a separate power source. To make the wattage calculation easier, I would suggest that you use [this free tool](https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator).

   I would also recommend that you consider about the possibility of adding newer parts and/or upgrading certain items.

   My build required around 300 watts of power. However, I chose a 500 watts PSU. This is because, I might include few parts in future and my power requirement might go up to 400 watts.
2. Modular:
   This is another major filter. Check this [link](https://support.nzxt.com/hc/en-us/articles/202798380-Full-Vs-Semi-Vs-Non-Modular-What-Are-The-Differences-) to know the basic difference between non-modular, semi-modular and fully modular PSUs.

   Non-modular PSUs are cheap but all the cables pre installed(which you cannot remove). Choosing this means you need to work harder on cable management so as to keep good ventilation to your case. If you have a case with a lot of free space, you can go for it. Research about your case to know better.

   Then comes semi-modular and fully modular PSUs with limited cables and no cables pre-attached to them. Fully modular is the highest priced.

   I had the NZXT S340 elite case. This has lot of space for cable management. So, I chose a non-modular PSU.
3. Efficiency:
   PSUs are rated like any other devices.  [80 Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus) certified PSUs are energy efficient than the ones that are non certified.

[image]
This table will help you with the basic difference between the 80 Plus PSUs.

```
Some brand try to mislead the consumers by not mentioning the correct 80 Plus details. I would not recommend going for a 80 Plus PSU with no medal attached to it. 

I chose a 80 Plus Bronze as it was under my budget and because it suited my limited hours of PC usage.
```

4. Form Factor:
   This depends on your case. If you case supports ATX form factor, choose a ATX PSU and similarly for other form factors. Research about your case to find the right form factor.

   I used [PC Part Picker](https://pcpartpicker.com/)  to check for the compatibility of the various parts of my build.

One last thing, I highly recommend choosing a PSU that is meant to be sold in your country/region. This is to avoid any issues with the regulations posed for electric/electronic items.

Though I am not an expert, I think I have covered the basics here. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong and/or lacking information.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, but moreover, I am concerned for availability of cables for my parts. My case has lots of space, so I too would be going for a non-modular hopefully. Can u please clarify if any PSU should have the necessary cables that I need in this case?

Comment: Also, from your modular/non-modular link, it seems that not only are the cables not pre-installed with modular, but they don't come with the PSU at all in the first place????

Comment: Glad it helped. To answer your question, all the PSUs(irrespective of modular or not) comes with necessary cables to all the components of the PC. Cables for your motherboard's power, CPU cooler, case fans, SATA, PCIE, and almost every other component that you might plug into the build are shipped with your PSU. The components you mentioned in your original question will definitely fit into your PSU. No additional cables required. You should only be worried about the excess cables that are left out after you complete your build ;)

Comment: Also, if you would want someone to help you choose a PSU for you, please post the required wattage and other specs based on my original answer. Go for any popular brands such as Corsair if you are very much worried.

Comment: My last concern is price.  I have spent around 1.6k until now, so I want a cheap but reliable PSU. Can you suggest a few specific models?

Comment: Corsair, EVGA, and Cooler Master are some of the reputable brands. There are a lot of PSUs available. I have only used a couple of them.  I currently have a Corsair CX model. This is a good one - makes a little noise but not in a disturbing way. The other PSUs I had are very old and should not be available now. Check http://www.jonnyguru.com/ for detailed reviews about a model that you may choose.